# Автообновление сертификатов в kubernetes кластере?

Tags: devops, kubernetes, x509certificate, certificate

Всем привет, у меня в кубернетис кластере есть 3 мастер ноды, сертификаты каждый раз обновляю вручную, как можно сделать автообновление сертификатов на всех master-node, то есть примерно так должно работать: у нас есть куб кластер и мы сделали обновление сертификата на одной мастер ноде и это повлияло на все остальные мастер ноды(2), подcкажите пожалуйста)